# If the data is not normally distributed and the skewness is = 0.208 SE of skewness is 0.144 , is it acceptable to use t-test?

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption

The sample size is 288 and by Shapiro- Wilk test the data is not normally distributed.

Comment: What was the p-value for the test?

Comment: What is the purpose of the test and what is your criterion for significance?